# Facebook Graph API Webhook for Manage Page Livestreaming

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get a webhook for a user's managed page going live and I've got the live_video webhook subscription in my Facebook App dashboard, but it's not going for my managed pages or those that I authorize when I authorize my app. I am using the pages_show_list scope so that my app is aware of the pages but that doesn't seem to be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed the `manage_pages` scope, and thus app review.